# MSBuild TargetOutputs missing assemblies

Tags: msbuild

I am building a solution file with code similar to the following;

```
<Target Name="Build">
  <MSBuild Projects="$(MySolution)"
           Targets="Build"
           BuildInParallel="false"
           Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);">     
    <Output ItemName="MyOutputs" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
  </MSBuild>

  <Message Importance="High" Text="MyOutputs=@(MyOutputs)" />
</Target>
```

And the output from that message that is supposed to show a list of assemblies that were built is missing some projects - projects that are actually being built (as they are shown being built in the rest of the log).

I found a descernible difference in the solution file regarding these projects: They each have a "ProjectSection" where others do not.

For example, this project is being sent to @(MyOutputs)

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Foo", "Foo\Foo.csproj", "{075C4960-951B-43FA-AAC5-99497C9C0EBC}"
EndProject
```

Whereas this one is not:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Bar", "Bar\Bar.csproj", "{EA7EEBE4-F7DB-4148-8B00-F49D747FA7B1}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {8B31D756-F858-43CA-81A7-5B4797554263} = {8B31D756-F858-43CA-81A7-5B4797554263}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

Would someone care to enlighten me on why this is happening, or what the consequences of removing these ProjectSections are?

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue was this

I was doing this:

```
msbuild.exe myproject.vbproj /T:Rebuild
msbuild.exe myproject.vbproj /T:Package
```

VS This:

```
msbuild.exe myproject.vbproj /T:Rebuild;Package
```

I have no idea why this work or why it didn't in the first place. But hope that helps.