# How to enumerate the dlls and exes generated when a .sln is compiled?

Tags: msbuild

I am using a MSBuild task to build a solution:

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(MySln)" ToolsVersion="4.0"/>
```

I want to get a list of the dlls/exes (their full path) output when above solution is built for subsequent processing. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [TargetOutputs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.tasks.msbuild.targetoutputs.aspx) [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164287.aspx) parameter:

```
    <MSBuild Projects="YourSolution.sln">
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="TheOutputs" />
    </MSBuild>

    <Message Text="@(TheOutputs)" Importance="High" />
```

Some other similar questions:

- [MSBuild TargetOutputs doesn't include Foo.exe.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513235/msbuild-targetoutputs-doesnt-include-foo-exe-config-file)
- [MSBuild TargetOutputs missing assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236289/msbuild-targetoutputs-missing-assemblies)